# Orbit sizes of $G=\operatorname{SO}^{+}_{2n}(2)$

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, magma, classical-groups

Let $G=\operatorname{SO}^{+}_{2n}(2)$. I did some Magma computation and found there were $3$ orbits on the natural $G$-set when $n=2,3,4$. The orbit sizes are $1$-$9$-$6$, $1$-$35$-$28$, $1$-$135$-$120$.

Is there a formula for the orbit sizes in general? Thank you.

Comment: $1$, $2^{2n-1}-2^{n-1}$, $2^{2n-1}+2^{n-1}-1$. (I am sure that is right, but I would need to think about it to prove it. I can look for a reference tomorrow.)

Comment: Exactly. These orbits are the origin, the isotropic vectors, and the non-isotropic vectors (or the other way round in Derek's answer)

Comment: I'd appreciate it a lot.

Comment: The singular vectors form a single orbit by Witt's lemma, similarly for non-singular vectors. More generally: for example Lemma 2.10.5 in "The Subgroup Structure of the Finite Classical Groups" by Kleidman and Liebeck

Comment: thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Mikko Korhonen said in the comments, the (non-zero) singular and non-singular vectors form single orbits by Witt's lemma.

So it remains to count the singular vectors, which are (row) vectors ${\mathbf v}$ over ${\mathbb F}_2$ such that ${\mathbf v}M {\mathbf v}^{\mathsf T} = 0$, where $M$ is the degree $2n$ matrix
$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}{\mathbf 0}&{\mathbf E}\\{\mathbf 0}&{\mathbf 0}\end{array}\right)\quad{\rm with}\quad {\mathbf E}=\left(\begin{array}{ccccc}0&0&\cdots&0&1\\0&0&\cdots&1&0\\&&\cdots&&\\0&1&\cdots&0&0\\1&0&\cdots&0&0\end{array}\right).$$
So we have to count the number of vectors ${\mathbf v}=(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{2n})$ with
$$x_nx_{n+1}+x_{n-1}x_{n+2}+\cdots x_1x_{2n}=0.$$
This is a straightforward induction. For the base case $m=1$ there are three pairs $x_1,x_2$ with $x_1x_2=0$. For the inductive step, we have $2^{2n-3} + 2^{n-2}$ choices for $x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1}x_{n+2},\ldots,x_{2n}$
with $x_{n-1}x_{n+2}+\cdots x_1x_{2n}=0$ and the number of of choices for $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{2n}$ is
$$3(2^{2n-3} + 2^{n-2}) + (2^{2n-3} -  2^{n-2}) = 2^{2n-1} + 2^{n-1}.$$